# How can I store canvas blob to an array?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I want to store several blobs from `canvas` elements using `canvas.toBlob` function to an array.

I've tried the code below which was useless. The result showed that the `.toBlob()` function works like an `async` function, and I have no knowledge about it.

```js
function saveAllPics(node_list) {
    // convert canvas element to png
    let pics = [];

    for (let canvas of node_list) {
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
            pics.push(blob);
            console.log(pics);
        });
    }

    let zipPics = function(pics) {
        // compress all pics into a zip file
        let zip = new JSZip();
        console.log("pics length：", pics.length);

        for (let i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
            let pic_data = pics[i];
            console.log(i);
            console.log(pic_data);
            zip.file("pic-" + String(i) + ".png", pic_data, { binary: true });
        }
        console.log(zip);
    }

    setTimeout(function(pics) { zipPics(pics); }, 2000);
```

And the result:

```
pics length： 0
{files: {…}, comment: null, root: '', clone: ƒ}
[Blob]
(2) [Blob, Blob]
(3) [Blob, Blob, Blob]
(4) [Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob]
(5) [Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob]
(6) [Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob]
(7) [Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob]
(8) [Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob, Blob]
```

My final goal is to collect several canvas elements, then merge them into a PDF file (in a user script). However, I have found I was unable to make a PDF, so I decided to use Node.js.

Then, I decided to take it a step further: download the PNGs and ask the users to use another Python script to merge them to a PDF file. That's why I need a zip containing these blobs.

Comment: @Spankied This question is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `canvas.toDataURL` helped a lot.

```
/**
 * store all canvas imgs as pngs into a zip file
 * @param {Array} node_list canvas元素列表
 */
function saveAllPics(node_list) {
    let zip = new JSZip();
    let n = node_list.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        let canvas = node_list[i];
        let data_base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
        let blob = atob(data_base64.split(",")[1]);
        zip.file(`page-${i}.png`, blob, { binary: true });
    }

    // promise.then(onCompleted, onRejected);
    zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function(content) {
        // see filesaver.js
        console.log(content);
        saveAs(content, "pics.zip");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The result showed that the toBlob function seems like an async function, and I have no knowledge about it.

Yeah, `toBlob()` accepts a callback, and you're using it now in your code.  But, we can easily clean this up using async, await, and Promises.  I would do this all in the same loop.  Untested code, but try something like this:

```
async function saveAllPics(canvases) {
  const zip = new JSZip();

  for (const [i, canvas] of canvases.entries()) {
    zip.file(
      // File name
      `pic-${i}.png`,

      // File data
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // If a blob is returned, success!... otherwise reject.
        canvas.toBlob(blob => blob ? resolve(blob) : reject());
      }),

      // JSZip Options
      { binary: true }
    );
  }

  return zip;
}
```

> By the way, my final goal is to collect several canvas elements then merge them to a pdf file (In a user script).

Have you considered one of the various JavaScript libraries for creating PDFs client-side?  For example, jsPDF:  https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have a new method to replace this code snippet. I've tried to learn something about async in the website: https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await, which made me more confused. Considering that it's not necessary to deal with async (if it really exists) in my task, I decided to take an alternative method.

Comment: And jsPDF works! Thanks.